# Struts2 exclude pattern not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, struts2

I'm using struts2 for GAE based app. I've a servlet to upload files like this -

```
@Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
      FileItemIterator it = upload.getItemIterator(req);
      while (it.hasNext()){
        FileItemStream item = it.next();
        if(item.isFormField()){
          System.out.println(item.getFieldName());
        }else {
          System.out.println(item.getFieldName()+" : "+item.getName());
        }
      }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

  }
```

In my struts.xml I've added exclude pattern as follows

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/_ah/*,/upload/*"/>
```

Here is a snippet of my web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.tutorial.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageUpload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tutorial.servlet.ImageUploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImageUpload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload/file</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I try and upload a file It still goes to struts rather than to my servlet. How do I solve this problem? I want file upload via a servlet.

Here is the stacktrace of the error -

```
Problem accessing /upload/file. Reason:

    java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.<clinit>(DiskFileItem.java:109)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.parseRequest(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:151)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.processUpload(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:90)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.parse(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequestWrapper.<init>(MultiPartRequestWrapper.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.wrapRequest(Dispatcher.java:753)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.wrapRequest(PrepareOperations.java:140)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:83)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:370)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: What is behaviour when using only one pattern /_ah/* or /upload/* in excludepattern? Is that working?

Comment: and what if you used /upload/file ?

Comment: If I used /upload/file it is handled by struts dispatcher. Which should not happen. This pattern should be ignored and web.xml should handle it.

Comment: Uploading files with struts2 is very simple... any reason you don't want to use the built in functionality?

Comment: I'm working on app engine. But even with struts2 I would prefer stream based approach and not tmp file based. Does struts2 allow stream based file uploading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expression style like this:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/_ah/.*,/upload/.*"/>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue of the struts.action.excludePattern was not working. When you said "regular expression" I double checked my pattern. Solved my problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in web.xml for struts2 filter to the specific extension that you use i.e `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>`

Comment: "If we change the filter mapping to something else, for example /*.html, we must take this in to account and extract the content that would normally be served from the Struts 2 jar files, or some other solution." http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to `struts.action.excludePattern` if you really want to use your custom servlet, is to define action which redirects to your servlet.

```
<action name="upload">
  <result>/upload_servlet</result>
</action>
```

Comment: For completeness, that's a forward, not a redirect.